# AJAX Testing Software Tools

Tags: ajax, testing

I"m looking for AJAX testing tools that are user friendly besides Selenium. I had tried Selenium but its difficult to learn. Any other tools?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried these?=> https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/list-of-ajax-automated-testing-and-debugging-tools

Comment: Tried but found none of the useful item

Comment: You have to customize them according to your usage. It would be not so difficult.